# VB return value

Tags: vb.net, parameters, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm currently migrating some code from VB6.0 to VB.NET and have noticed an issue. I'm fairly new to VB6.0 and I'm now aware that multiple values can be returned by the following:

```
Function test(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Long

str1 = "Hello World1"
str2 = "Hello World2"

test = 0

End Function
```

When I debug I can see that the parameter passed is now updated. However my issue is that VB.NET doesn't seem to do this. How can I do this in VB.NET?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VB6, parameters are passed ***by reference*** by default, where as in VB.NET, they are passed ***by value*** by default.  That explains why it behaves differently.  If you want to retain the old behavior and pass the parameters by reference, you need to be explicit about it (notice the additional `ByRef` keywords):

```
Function test(ByRef str1 As String, ByRef str2 As String) As Long

str1 = "Hello World1"
str2 = "Hello World2"

test = 0 'don't forget to migrate this line to VB.NET as well

End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

In VB.NET the default way of passing parameters is by value (`ByVal`) instead of by reference (`ByRef`). To get the VB 6 behaviour you need to make the parameters `ByRef`:

```
Function test(ByRef str1 As String, ByRef str2 As String) As Long

  str1 = "Hello World1"
  str2 = "Hello World2"

  Return 0

End Function
```

In VB 6 the default was by reference because it was more expensive to pass parameters by value as objects needed to be copied. In VB.NET the default is by value as objects doesn't need to be copied, instead a reference to the object is passed as the parameter value.

In VB.NET you also have the `Return` statement that you can use to return the value. (Note that it will exit the function, which assigning the value to the function name doesn't do.)